# Can playing an amp at minimum volumes (<1%) be harmful to it?

Tags: guitar, amplifiers

I have Peavey Vypyr VIP 2. It's a solid-state 40w amplifier.

I don't own any lower power amps, so I use it at my apartment for practicing. It does have a headphone output, but I wanted to know if there's any way playing a solid-state amp at extremely low volumes through the speaker can harm it.

I want to say, that this does not have any fundament behind it. I just want to make sure it's not dangerous for the amp.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: No. Not at all.

Answer (score 7):

Amps are designed to run at pretty well any volume - although high volumes can be dangerous - for the speaker, neighbours, and your ears. Although at low volumes, the quality of sound is often disappointing. You could consider having a small practice amp as well, a pre-loved one I bought recently cost me £10. Hardly breaking the bank, and good enough for use in a room, quietly, and even with 'phones.

Answer (score 4):

A few thoughts on this.

- Playing at low volume will not damage your amp. Playing at the highest volume might.
- If your amp isn't playing low enough for you, consider practising unplugged. (Seriously).
- Would playing at a different time of day make your practise more acceptable?
- You could try getting yourself a practise amp, ask at your local guitar shop, they can be pretty cheap.
- There's also quite a lot of kit with headphone outputs. Cheaper options are:

  - Effects pedals and a cheap mixer.
  - iRig phone adaptors (get one compatible with your phone)

Comment: With a volumke pedal added to the end of the chain after the effects loop, you can lower the volume using the volume pedal even more I think.

Answer (score 0):

Running amps at low volume just makes it harder to get the sound where you want it (tone). Think of trying to pour a straw's worth of water into a riverbed. Almost no effect, but pour a river through a straw... The best thing I can tell you is, go rent a rehearsal room for 20 bucks for a couple hours and go buck wild.